# A subset of [0,1] of measure 1 is dense in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $E \subseteq [0,1]$ is a lebesgue measurable set with $m(E)=1$. Show that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$.
I would appreciate any useful hints.

Comment: Could $E$ miss an entire subinterval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose there exists a non-empty open $\;A\subset[0,1]\;$ such that $\;E\cap A=\emptyset\;$, and let $\;a,b\in[0,1]\;,\;\;a<b$ be such that $\;(a,b)\subset A\;$ . Observe that $\;m(a,b)=b-a>0\;$, so then also $\;m(A)>0\;$ , and thus

$$1=m(E)<m(E)+m(A)=m(E\cup A)\le m[0,1]=1$$

which is a contradiction

Comment: I think you meant $A$ to be an open set. Right?

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you, yes of course. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $E$ is dense in $X$ iff $E \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for any open set $A$ of $X$.

Comment: This is the definition of a dense subset of $X$ in the abstract topological setting.  A useful hint (in my opinion) needs to tie the definition to the measurability property of $E$ posited as a subset of $[0,1]$.  Please improve your overly terse answer by adding material to make such a connection.

Comment: TS asked for any useful hint and not a full answer. Recalling the definition of what a dense set is would to me, at least, be a useful hint.

Comment: FYI, I agree with @hardmath That said, what you're wanting to do would work better if you defined dense in a more concrete way, such as $E$ is *not dense in* $[0,1]$ if and only if there exists an interval $I$ such that $I \subseteq [0,1]$ and $I$ is of positive length and $E \cap I = \emptyset.$

Comment: Because I though about phrasing it this way, I have to agree with you. However putting anything more into it would make it more of a solution than a hint in my opinion.