# Brezis' exercise 8.3: Helly’s selection theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $I := (0,1)$. I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.3** Assume that $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{1, 1}(I)$. Show that there is a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $(u_{n_k} (x))$ converges to a limit for every $x \in [0, 1]$.

My approach is different from the author's guideline. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you have a check on it?

---

By [Theorem 8.8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763660/brezis-theorem-8-8-how-to-get-the-inequality-u-l-inftyi-leq-c-u) (in the same book), the injection $W^{1, 1}(I) \subset L^1 (I)$ is compact because $I$ is bounded. Then there is a subsequence $(n_k)$ and $v \in L^1 (I)$ such that $\|u_{n_k}-v\|_{L^1} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 0$. Up to a further subsequence, we can assume $u_{n_k} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} v$ a.e. on $I$.

Let $E$ be a null subset of $I$ such that $u_{n_k} (x) \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} v(x)$ for all $x \in E^c := I \setminus E$. Clearly, $E^c$ [is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3770315/368425) in $I$.

Fix $x \in E$. It suffices to prove that $(u_{n_k} (x))_k$ is a Cauchy sequence. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $y \in E^c$ such that $|x-y| < \varepsilon$. We have $(u_{n_k} (y))_k$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $C := \sup_n \|u_n\|_{W^{1, 1}} < \infty$
$$
\begin{align*}
| u_{n_i} (x) - u_{n_j} (x) | &= | (u_{n_i} (x) - u_{n_i} (y)) -  (u_{n_j} (x) - u_{n_j} (y)) + (u_{n_i} (y) - u_{n_j} (y))| \\
&\le | u_{n_i} (x) - u_{n_i} (y) | + | u_{n_j} (x) - u_{n_j} (y) |+ |u_{n_i} (y) - u_{n_j} (y)| \\
&\le (\| u_{n_i}' \|_{L^1} + \| u_{n_j}' \|_{L^1}  )  |x-y|+ |u_{n_i} (y) - u_{n_j} (y)| \\
&\le 2\varepsilon C+ |u_{n_i} (y) - u_{n_j} (y)|.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows.

Comment: Looks fine to me, it would be good to have a reference that $W^{1,1}$-functions are absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you so much for your verification!