# Brezis' exercise 8.30.6: $u_n \to u$ in $H^2 (I)$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Let $k \in \mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$. We consider the space
$$
V := \{v \in H^1 (I) : v(0) = kv(1)\},
$$
and the symmetric bilinear form $a$ defined on $V$ by
$$
a(u, v) = \int_I [ u'v' + uv ]  - \left ( \int_I u \right) \left ( \int_I v \right).
$$

I am trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Exercise 8.30**
>
> 1. Check that $V$ is a closed subspace of $H^1 (I)$.
>
> In what follows, $V$ is equipped with the Hilbert structure induced by the $H^1$ inner product.
>
> 2. Prove that $a$ is a continuous and coercive bilinear form on $V$.
> 3. Deduce that for every $f \in L^2 (I)$ there exists a unique solution of the problem
>    $$
>    (1) \quad
>    u \in V
>    \quad \text{and} \quad
>    a(u, v)=\int_I f v
>    \quad \forall v \in V.
>    $$
> 4. Show that the solution $u$ of $(1)$ belongs to $H^2 (I)$ and satisfies
>    $$
>    (2) \quad
>    \begin{cases}
>    -u'' + u-\int_I u = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
>    u(0)=k u(1) \text { and } u'(1)=k u'(0).
>    \end{cases}
>    $$
> 5. Conversely, prove that any function $u \in H^2(I)$ satisfying $(2)$ is a solution of $(1)$.
> 6. Let $k_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ for all $n$. Assume $k_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} k \neq 1$. Set
>    $$
>    V_n = \{v \in H^1(I) : v(0)=k_n v(1)\} .
>    $$
>    Given $f \in L^2 (I)$, let $u_n$ be the solution of
>    $$
>    (1_n) \quad
>    u_n \in V_n
>    \quad \text { and } \quad
>    a(u_n, v) = \int_I f v
>    \quad \forall v \in V_n .
>    $$
>    Prove that $u_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} u$ in $H^1 (I)$, where $u$ is the solution of $(1)$. Deduce that $u_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} u$ in $H^2 (I)$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt of (6.). Could you please have a check on it?

---

From (4.) and (5.), we get that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$. I [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824802/brezis-exercise-8-30-2-a-is-a-continuous-and-coercive-bilinear-form-on-v) that
$$
a(v, v) \ge \varepsilon_n \| v \|_{H^1},
\quad \forall v \in V_n,
$$
where $\varepsilon_n := \frac{(k_n-1)^2}{2(k_n^2+1)}$. Because $k_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} k \neq 1$, WLOG we can assume that there is $\varepsilon >0$ such that
$$
a(v, v) \ge \varepsilon \| v \|_{H^1},
\quad \forall v \in \bigcup_n V_n.
$$

It follows that
$$
\|f\|_{L^2} \|u_n\|_{H^1} \ge \|f\|_{L^2} \|u_n\|_{L^2} \ge \int_I f u_n =a(u_n, u_n) \ge \varepsilon \| u_n \|_{H^1},
$$
which implies $\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \|f\|_{L^2} \ge \| u_n \|_{H^1}$. Then $(u_n)$ is bounded in $H^1 (I)$. It follows from the first equation of $(2)$ that $(u_n'')$ is bounded in $L^2 (I)$. Then $(u_n)$ is bounded in $H^2 (I)$. Notice that $H^2 (I)$ is uniformly convex and thus reflexive. We denoted by $\rightharpoonup$ the weak convergence in the weak topology of $H^2 (I)$.

Let $(n_k)$ be an arbitrary sub-sequence of $\mathbb N$. Then $(u_{n_k})_k$ is bounded in $H^2 (I)$. There is $v \in H^2 (I)$ and a sub-sequence (also denoted by $(u_{n_k})_k$ for simplicity) such that $u_{n_k} \rightharpoonup v$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812535/does-f-n-f-l2-to-0-imply-f-n-to-f-in-the-weak-topology-of-h1-i) $\| u_{n_k} - v \|_{L^2} \to 0$ and $\| u_{n_k}' - v' \|_{L^2} \to 0$. By Helly’s selection [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783589/brezis-exercise-8-3-helly-s-selection-theorem), we can extract a further sub-sequence (also denoted by $(u_{n_k})_k$ for simplicity) such that $u_{n_k} \to v$ *everywhere* and $u_{n_k}' \to v'$ *everywhere*.

We have $u_{n_k} \rightharpoonup v$ together with $-u_{n_k}'' + u_{n_k} - \int_I u_{n_k} = f$ implies $-v'' + v - \int_I v = f$. We have $u_{n_k} (0) = k_{n_k} u_{n_k} (1)$ and $u_{n_k}'(1) = k_{n_k} u_{n_k}'(0)$ together with $u_{n_k} \to v$ everywhere and $u_{n_k}' \to v'$ everywhere imply $v (0) = k v (1)$ and $v'(1)=k v'(0)$. To sum up, $v$ is a solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
-v'' + v-\int_I v = f \quad \text {on} \quad I, \\
v(0)=k v(1) \text { and } v'(1)=k v'(0).
\end{cases}
$$

By uniqueness of $(1)$, we get $u=v$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to show $u_n\to u$. You already showed that $\|u_n\|_{H^1},\|u\|_{H^1}\le \frac1\varepsilon\|f\|_{L^2}$. Now
$$ |u_n(1)|\le |u_n(1)-u_n(x)|+|u_n(x)|,|u_n'(0)|\le |u_n'(0)-u'_n(x)|+|u'_n(x)| $$
which implies
$$\begin{eqnarray}
|u_n(1)|&=&\int_I|u_n(1)|\le \int_I|u_n(1)-u_n(x)|+\int_I|u_n(x)|\\
&\le&\int_I\bigg|\int_x^1u_n'(t)dt\bigg|+\|u_n\|_{L^2}\\
&\le&\|u'_n\|_{L^2}+\|u_n\|_{L^2}\le  \frac1\varepsilon\|f\|_{L^2},\\
|u_n'(0)|&=&\int_I|u_n'(0)|\le \int_I|u_n'(0)-u_n'(x)|+\int_I|u_n'(x)|\\
&\le&\int_I\bigg|\int_0^xu_n''(t)dt\bigg|+\|u_n'\|_{L^2}\\
&\le&2\|u_n\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2}\le (\frac2\varepsilon+1)\|f\|_{L^2},\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
Let $v_n=u_n-u$ and then $v_n$ satisfies
$$ -v_n''+v_n-\int_I v_n=0 \tag{*}$$
and the boundary conditions
$$ v_n(0)=u_n(0)-u(0)=k_nu_n(1)-ku(1)=(k_n-k)u_n(1)+kv_n(1)=o(1)+kv_n(1) $$
and
$$ v_n'(1)=u_n'(0)-u'(0)=k_nu_n'(0)-ku'(0)=(k_n-k)u_n'(0)+kv_n'(0)=o(1)+kv_n'(0). $$
Multiplying (*) by $v_n$ and using IBP, one has
$$ \|v_n'\|^2_{L^2}+\|v_n\|^2_{L^2}=\|v_n\|_{L^1}^2+v_n(1)v_n'(1)-v_n(0)v_n'(0)\le\|v_n\|_{L^2}^2+o(1)$$
and hence
$$ \|v_n'\|^2_{L^2}\le o(1). $$
So
$$ v_n'\to 0 \text{ in }L^2 $$
which also implies $v_n\to0$ in $L^2$.