# Brezis' exercise 6.20.2: prove that $0 \notin EV(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Given $u \in E$, set
> $$
> T u(x) = \int_0^x u(t) \, d t .
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $T \in \mathcal{K}(E)$.
> 2. Determine $E V(T)$ and $\sigma(T)$.
> 3. Give an explicit formula for $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ when $\lambda \in \rho(T)$.
> 4. Determine $T^{\star}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes I could not recognize in below attempt that $0 \notin EV(T)$. Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

We have $\dim E= \infty$ and $T \in \mathcal{K}(E)$, [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4736170/368425) $0\in \sigma(T)$. First, we prove that $0 \notin EV(T)$. Let $u, v\in E$ such that $Tu=Tv$.

- Then $\int_0^x (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ for a.e. $x\in (0, 1)$.
- [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736345/a-subset-of-0-1-of-measure-1-is-dense-in-0-1) $\int_0^x (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ for every $x$ in some dense subset of $(0, 1)$.
- By dominated convergence theorem, $\int_0^x (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ for every $x \in (0, 1)$.
- Then $\int_I (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ for every sub-interval $I$ of $(0, 1)$.
- By dominated convergence theorem, $\int_B (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ for every Borel subset $B$ of $(0, 1)$.
- [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4547251/368425) $u-v=0$ a.e.
- Then $T$ is injective.

Comment: How do you go from integral over $I$ to integral over $B$? Use Lebesgue's differentiation theorem instead of DCT for this.

Comment: @geetha290krm Because Lebesgue measure is regular, we can approximate $B$ be open set. On the other hand, we [can](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals) approximate open set by open interval.

Comment: You can approximate $B$ by a finite union of intervals in a particular sense. Certainly, you cannot find  sequence if intervals $I_n$ such that $1_{I_n}$ converges a.e. to $1_B$.  So you have to explain how you are applying DCT.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have posted a fix as below answer. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: It is correct, but I still think that Lebsgue's Theorem is the right approach, since it gives the result immediately.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sure. It's also good that I come up with my own approach ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @geetha290krm pointed out in a comment, the passing from intervals to Borel sets is not justified. Below is my fix.

---

Let $\mathcal C$ be the collection of all sub-intervals of $(0, 1)$. Then $\mathcal C$ is a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Definitions). Let $\mathcal D$ be the collection of all Borel subsets $B$ of $(0, 1)$ such that $\int_B (u(t)-v(t)) \, d t = 0$ . Then $\mathcal D$ is a [$\lambda$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Definitions). We have proved that $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal D$. By [Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537342/dynkins-pi-lambda-theorem-is-equivalent-to-monotone-class-theorem), $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \mathcal D$. Thus $\mathcal D$ indeed coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(0, 1)$.